# how to create table using like command?

Tags: hive

I try to create table with like keyword and also add serdeproperties but i am getting following error, can you please provide solution  for this.

hive> describe people;

OK

emp_no  int

birth_date  string
first_name  string
last_name   string
gender  string
hire_date   string
Time taken: 0.237 seconds

hive> create external table if not exists employeemapping like people stored by "org.yong3.hive.mongo.MongoStorageHandler"

> with serdeproperties ( "mongo.column.mapping" = "emp_no,birth_date,first_name,last_name,gender,hire_date" )
>       tblproperties ( "mongo.host" = "localhost", "mongo.port" = "27017",
>       "mongo.db" = "pelica", "mongo.collection" = "employees" );
>   FAILED: ParseException line 1:64 mismatched input 'stored' expecting EOF near 'people'

Answer (score 0):

ParseException line 1:64 mismatched input 'stored' expecting EOF near 'people' --- states that like is not supposed to be there.

creating external-non-native using LIKE (TABLE SCHEMA COPY) won't work it seems, this is a per my understanding.

below mentioned something relevent to your question(may or may not help you).

pls refer issues in cwiki > Hive > StorageHandlers

open issues: (last one on the issues list)

CREATE TABLE AS SELECT is currently prohibited for creating a non-native table. It should be possible to support this, although it may not make sense for all storage handlers. For example, for HBase, it won't make sense until the storage handler is capable of automatically filling in column mappings.